# Woocommerce - Order Tracking Link

Tags: woocommerce

I want to include a 'check my order status' link in the thank you email. Woocommerce comes with a order tracking form, but the user has to input their order id and email. Is there a way to show the tracking page without going through the input form?

I know my accounts has a view order link, but that would only work if the user is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show an order tracking link in your email. It is a bit convoluted way and will take some time. It is much easier to let the user input his information. This makes things a lot less complicated. But if you absolutely need the order tracking in the email, then,

1. Put this information somewhere other than your secured site,
2. Make sure you update this information regularly,
3. Take the ID of
   this information from your database and make a GET endpoint(hoping
   its a web application), such that it takes in the ID number of the
   information and displays it,
4. This GET link needs to be embedded
   into a HTML form/template which you are sending as the email

If you want the whole implementation, you need to specify the tech stack you are using and other details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show one tracking page which page customers/users can search their order status without login, then you can use the plugin [Order Tracker for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-order-tracker/)

If you use the plugin then the user can check his/her order status without login/hassle free, and also you don't need to add any extra tracking number, user can search using their order ID and phone number.

you can use it the very easy way, like making a page template or using the [cbwct-order-tracker] shortcode, anytime anywhere, and it’s also working with ajax.

You can watch the video for the plugin documentation on how to use that plugin here is the
[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfE7GuqwlbA)